# Fill blank cells of a pandas dataframe column by matching with another datafame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, lets call it `df1` that looks like this (the follow is just a sample to give an idea of the dataframe):

| Ac | Tp | Id | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF | 100 | 200 | 45 |
| Asset | FC |  | 52 | 48 | 15 |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT | 45 | 58 | 15 |
| Tax | Other |  | 48 | 45 | 78 |

And I want to fill the blank spaces using a in the `'Id'` column using the next auxiliar dataframe, lets call it `df2` (again, this is just a sample):

| Ac | Tp | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF |
| Asset | FC | IQ_AST |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT |
| Tax | Other | IQ_TAX |
| Income | BAL | IQ_INC |
| Invest | FC | IQ_INV |

To get `df1` dataframe, looking like this:

| Ac | Tp | Id | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF | 100 | 200 | 45 |
| Asset | FC | IQ_AST | 52 | 48 | 15 |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT | 45 | 58 | 15 |
| Tax | Other | IQ_TAX | 48 | 45 | 78 |

I tried with this line of code but it did not work:

```
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].mask(df1('nan')).fillna(df1['Ac'].map(df2('Ac')['Id']))
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two frames on `Ac` and `Tp` columns and assign the `Id` column from this result to `df1.Id`. This works similar to Excel Vlookup functionality.

```py
ac_tp = ['Ac', 'Tp']
df1['Id'] = df1[ac_tp].merge(df2[[*ac_tp, 'Id']])['Id']
```

[image: res]

Comment: I tried using your help, but the result was that it did not search the corresponding 'Ac' of the missing value in the 'Id' column, but fill it with the next one that was not blank. Can you help me out?

Comment: @ValeriaArango could you explain with an example? I don’t quite understand what you mean by “fill it with the next one”. The code works on the example you gave in the OP so can’t really deduce anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein you could also try:

```
df['Id'] = (df.merge(df2, on = ['Ac', 'Tp'])
 .pipe(lambda d: d['Id_x'].mask(d['Id_x'].isnull(), d['Id_y'])))

       Ac     Tp       Id  2020  2021  2022
0  Efecty     FC    IQ_EF   100   200    45
1   Asset     FC   IQ_AST    52    48    15
2    Debt    P&G  IQ_DEBT    45    58    15
3     Tax  Other   IQ_TAX    48    45    78
```

Comment: I tried using your help, but the result was that it did not search the corresponding 'Ac' of the missing value in the 'Id' column, but fill it with the next one that was not blank. Can you help me out?

Comment: Could you give me some additional explanation and what you expect. I will edit my answer then.